# How do I set the FunctionDeclaration property for eslint indentation rules?

Tags: javascript, eslint

According to the [documentation for indent](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/indent), there is a `FunctionDeclaration` property taking an object. I would like to set the `parameters` property of `FunctionDeclaration` to `2`. However, I still get an error about my indentation being wrong.

I suspect my format in the eslint settings file is wrong. I've tried looking in the documentation and elsewhere for a sample of a complete setting for `indent` to make sure my formatting is right, but I can't find any. Here is the relevant part of the setting file:

```
"indent": [
  "error",
  "tab",
  {
    "FunctionDeclaration": {
      "body": 1,
      "parameters": 2
    },
    "SwitchCase": 1
  }
],
```

The `SwitchCase` property and all the others are working just fine, so it's strange that this one property in particular isn't working. I also tried setting both `body` and `parameters` to various values but that seems to have no effect whatsoever on eslint's errors.

Edit:

Code causing the error:

```js
constructor(word, countable = true, proper = false, alwaysSingular = false,
        alwaysPlural = false, irregularPlural = false, definite = false, indefinite = false){
```

Again, I get the same error regardless of the numbers I put into `body` and `parameters`, but don't get an error if I set the indentation in the code to one indent.

eslint version `6.14.4`

Comment: It would make sense to include the code causing the error. And the version of eslint.

Comment: Thanks, @DaveNewton, I just added those now.

Comment: Unrelated, but that’s... a pretty ragged constructor. I’d refactor then worry about indentation.